# Radius of convergence for recursively defined power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, power-series

Given $\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_n}=\frac{n(n-1)+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$, how may one find the radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$? The problem would of course be easy if the numerator was $n+1$ rather than $n+2$, but alas! My lecturer used something to do with splitting the series into its even part and its odd part... But I really wasn't able to follow what was being done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$, then 
$$r_nr_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_n}=\frac{n(n-1)+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}.$$
Assuming that the series has a radius of convergence $R$ and $\frac{1}{R}=\lim_{n \to \infty}r_n$. In which case, we have 
$$\frac{1}{R^2}=\lim_{n \to \infty}r_nr_{n+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n(n-1)+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=1.$$
So $R=1$.

Comment: Thank you, although why does $R=lim_{n \to \infty} r_n$? Is that just the result of some fundamental property that I'm missing?

Comment: @cal I had a typo. It should have been $1/R$ (I've fixed it now). This is from the ratio test.

Answer (score 0):

The given recurrence is precisely the expression of the ratio test. As the limit of the fraction is $1$, so is the radius of convergence.

Now the recurrence only relates terms of the *same parity* so that in fact you have two interleaved sequences ($a_0,a_1$ can be specified independently). These two sequences obviously have the same radius and so has their sum.